# Open datepicker on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, preventdefault

I want my datepicker to open only under condition, in this case the presence of a class, here's the not working code:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disableDatepicker')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: but i think that you need to enable/disable on certain event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be work

```
$("input").datepicker({ 
         beforeShow: function(a,b){ 
             if ($(this).hasClass('disableDatepicker')) return false;  
         } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scTwm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'not' selector or method

Selector

```
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger:not(.disableDatepicker)').click(function(e){
    //your code
});
```

Method

```
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').not('.disableDatepicker').click(function(e){
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to what you did, you can find a live example here that I've created for you ( http://jsbin.com/kikok/1/ ).

Or check the code that is self explanatory:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".click").on("click", function(e){

     if ( $(this).hasClass("prevent") ) {
       console.log("hasClass prevent!");
       e.preventDefault();
     }

  });

});
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <a class="click" href="//google.com" target="_blank">Click1</a>
    <a class="click prevent"  href="//google.com" target="_blank">Click2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!